# UISearchBar misplaced when in the detail of a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using an UISplitViewController and on the detail view I have an UISearchController, but when the search bar gets active, the component suddenly goes to the right and half of it stay out of screen.

I tried to post the image, but sadly "You need at least 10 reputation to post images.", so I uploaded here http://iferiados.com.br/bug.jpg

It occurs only in the iPad and only when the display mode is .AllVisible, if I expand the detail view to all screen, the search bar stay in the correct place.

My code for the search controller:

```
var searchController: UISearchController!

//and in the viewDidLoad():

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Procure pelo nome"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have any necessary constraints for the search bar. If you are configuring it through the storyboard then make sure you have all constraints or check out apple's documentation regarding constraints. Also, if you say the problem only occurs on the iPad, make sure that at the bottom of the storyboard "Any Any" is selected.

Comment: I'm creating the UISearchController programmatically, so there's no search component on my storyboard. And yes, it's Any Any. I'm starting to think that is a bug with UISplitViewController, when I change the 'preferredDisplayMode' it works fine.